# Creating a layout that has a fixed header, fixed sidebar nav, fixed content with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am creating a layout for a web application using FlexBox. Please note that I am not trying to use bootstrap for this. I just want to do it in plain flexbox css.

**Here is the structure I want:**

Row1: Fixed header that is 64px tall.
Row2: Fixed sidenav that takes up 250px of left side, Fixed content that takes up the remainder of right side.

```
<div id="row1">
     <div class="header"></div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
     <div class="sidenav"></div>
     <div class="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

**The key here** is that the sidenav and the main-content should both be 100% of the screen with their own scroll bar. The actual browser scroll bar should never show horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Where are your attempts, have you done anything to try and figure this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make `body` a flex `column` at `100vh` height, set `#row2` to grow and use `overflow-y: scroll` on `.sidenav` and `.main-content`

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.header {
  height: 64px;
}
.sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
.main-content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.sidenav, .main-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
     <div class="header">header</div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
     <div class="sidenav">foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br></div>
     <div class="main-content">foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this example the sidenav doesn't have its own scroll bar.

Comment: @BlakeRivell did you read my answer? I explained it was unclear and what to do if that's what you wanted. Just updated the answer though.

Comment: Ok I am checking it out now, I was trying to get it to work similar to this site: https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list

Comment: Not sure whos answer to mark as correct because both work. Seems like yours uses more flexbox.

Comment: @BlakeRivell which answer are you comparing it to?

Comment: Dippas answer which does exactly what I want also, just seems like it isn't using flex as much. My goal is to ultimately use this with Angular and Angular-Material, Flex-Layout modules. The flex-layout module allows you to add flex directives to angular components. Posting that question would be way too complicated though. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Comment: @BlakeRivell None of these 2 guys worries to much about which you pick :) ... not really why they posted an answer

Comment: @BlakeRivell yeah he's using `calc()` for the height of `#row2` instead of making the parent a `flex` parent and using `flex-grow` for `#row2`. IMO, my solution for that is better since it doesn't use `64px` as a fixed value twice in CSS. If you update the height of `#row1`, then with dippas' answer, you have to change `64px` in 2 places, and in my solution you only specify the height in `#row1` or the header, then the rest of the page automatically adapts to fit the space. I'm also utilzing `flex-basis` instead of width/height, like Dippas is using.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I agree, and if you see my last post that I am trying to now implement this using: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout in Angular I believe your answer will help more.

Comment: @BlakeRivell he also has some unnecessary `width: 100%` css and left off semicolons from a bunch of his properties ;) Oh and `position: fixed` on sidenav... yeah I dunno, I guess we both give the same output, but dippas is using a mix of things, and I'm primarily or only using flex properties to create the layout.

Comment: @MichaelCoker this is why I marked your answer as correct because it is truly using flex for what it is.

Comment: @BlakeRivell you chose well! haha.

Comment: ahahahahahahahahahah  just that ahahahahahah

Comment: @MichaelCoker can you briefly explain what is going on with each flex property in each class. I am going to try and learn flex now but would like a head start.

Comment: @BlakeRivell you mean the shorthand `flex` property or which ones specifically?

Comment: @BlakeRivell next time be more specific in your question about what you want,  if you say "fixed header" then its a fixed header using position fixed to be fixed all the time. just an advice

Comment: @MichaelCoker In flex I understand there are containers and then elements within containers. It seems like you are using the body as a container (which is obviously is) and making flex-direction column instead of row, then you are doing specific flex numbers on all of the children. I am slightly confused about why there are 3 numbers each time. Once again I can definitely youtube or google this stuff which I am about to do, but figured Id ask while your here.

Comment: @BlakeRivell yeah there are parents and children. And children can be parents if they have content, too. So body is a flex `column` (stacks on top instead of horizontaly in a row). `#row1` will `flex-grow` to fill the available space. sidenav has a `flex-basis` of 250px, and the main content will also `flex-grow` to fill the available space. The shorthand `flex` takes 3 values - `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`. This is the guide I followed to learn flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @MichaelCoker perfect! Now the numbers make sense! Do I really have to put flex on the body is this a common thing or can I simply make a wrapper for everything and put flex column on that instead? Also what is with the 100vh I noticed it is mandatory or everything breaks, why not 100%;

Comment: @BlakeRivell you can put a wrapper around everything and use flex on that instead of body, but no harm in using it on body unless you have a specific reason not to do that. It's less markup without an additional wrapper.

Comment: 100vh seems to work better than 100% in my experience. If you use 100%, you also need to add that to `html` (so like `html,body { height: 100%; }`). Either way

Comment: @MichaelCoker By any chance do you use Angular 2? The same exact sample you gave me doesn't work in a brand new angular 2 project. Makes no sense.

Comment: @BlakeRivell nope

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using flexbox

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

#row1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 64px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#row2 {
  display: flex;
  top: 64px;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
  width: 100%
}

.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(100% - 64px);
background: green;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.main-content {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div class="header"></div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
  <div class="sidenav">lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text
    lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text end </div>
  <div class="main-content">lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text
    lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum
    text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text lipsum text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just in case I added `overflow:scroll` to it , still don't get the fixed header/footer.

Comment: Yeah the sidebar is what has been killing me in this scenario and the reason I posted the question. Otherwise you got everything else right. Why is the scroll only working for the content?

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaah :) ...plus 1